# Does the Bot Framework support the Korean language?

Tags: botframework

I have been asked if it is possible to build a bot that supports Korean using the Microsoft Bot Framework.

I can see Localization instructions which describe how to translate prompts into different languages.  I have also read that it is possible to use Microsoft Translator so that a bot can switch to the language of the user.

Is there a list of supported languages?  Does this extend to Cognitive Services such as LUIS or QnA Maker which the bot may be calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of what OmG said, Korean is a supported language within the Bot Framework. Korean is also LUIS supported, as seen in the image below.

[image]

To get this list of cultures, it is also possible to do a GET request with your LUIS Programmatic API Key. To do this, access this link with your Key: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/cultures?subscription-key=**Your-LUIS-Programmatic-API-KEY**

As indicated by its FAQ, the [QnA Maker](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/QnAMaker/documentation/faqs#does-the-qna-maker-support-non-en-languages) also supports other languages, but has only been extensively tested with English.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of supported languages in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456380.aspx) (see in the following by running the snippet)

```html
<div>
          <table Responsive="true" summary="table"><tr class="thead" Responsive="true"><th scope="col">Language Code</th><th scope="col">English Name</th></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>af</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Afrikaans</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ar</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Arabic</p>
                </td></tr>
     <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>bs-Latn</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Bosnian (Latin)</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>bg</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Bulgarian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ca</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Catalan</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>zh-CHS</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Chinese Simplified</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>zh-CHT</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Chinese Traditional</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>hr</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Croatian</p>
                </td></tr>     
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>cs</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Czech</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>da</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Danish</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>nl</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Dutch</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>en</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>English</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>et</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Estonian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>fi</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Finnish</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>fr</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>French</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>de</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>German</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>el</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Greek</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ht</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Haitian Creole</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>he</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Hebrew</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>hi</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Hindi</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>mww</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Hmong Daw</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>hu</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Hungarian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>id</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Indonesian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>it</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Italian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ja</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Japanese</p>
                </td></tr>
      <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>sw</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Kiswahili</p>
                </td></tr>       
     <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>tlh</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Klingon</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>tlh-Qaak</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Klingon (pIqaD)</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ko</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Korean</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>lv</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Latvian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>lt</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Lithuanian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ms</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Malay</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>mt</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Maltese</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>no</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Norwegian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>fa</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Persian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>pl</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Polish</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>pt</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Portuguese</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>otq</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Querétaro Otomi</p>
                </td></tr>  
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ro</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Romanian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ru</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Russian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>sr-Cyrl</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Serbian (Cyrillic)</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>sr-Latn</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Serbian (Latin)</p>
                </td></tr>     
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>sk</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Slovak</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>sl</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Slovenian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>es</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Spanish</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>sv</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Swedish</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>th</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Thai</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>tr</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Turkish</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>uk</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Ukrainian</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>ur</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Urdu</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>vi</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Vietnamese</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>cy</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Welsh</p>
                </td></tr>
              <tr><td data-th="Language Code">
                <p>yua</p>
                </td><td data-th="English Name">
                <p>Yucatec Maya</p>
                </td></tr>     
            </table>

        </div>
```

As you can see, Korean is a supported language. Also, you can find about this issue in more details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/9).